# ScrollIntoView Not Working in Listbox if Wrap Panel used

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I want to show items  as gallery view in Listbox. So i have used Wrap Panel its working well with scrolling.

But I have Next and Previous button to scroll up, down of items. I have used the ScrollIntoView for that. But it is not working when we used wrap panel.

Please Help me.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It is poorly worded, but most Silverlight developers would understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to support `ScrollIntoView`, the panel that hosts the items much implement `IScrollInfo`, you can see that panels such as [VirtualizingStackPanel implement this interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx), however WrapPanel does not - so it will not support this feature.

As an alternative, you can implement this functionality yourself. Look at the WP7 Jump List control:

http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72741#1502048

Scroll to the `CategoryButton_Click` method. This first locates the element that the container should scroll to, then determines its vertical location, finally, it scrolls the `ScrollViewer` via a `Storyboard`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the wrap panel inside scroll view and set the height of wrap panel to automatic. This works fine for me.

Comment: can you pls put some example code. I have tried like the following code, it gives error to me    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="900" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

Comment: Putting WrapPanel + ScrollViewer inside a ListBoxItem is a bad idea, as the scrolling will conflict between the ListBox and the ScrollViewer. May be you can redesign your UI and use proper approach.

Comment: Normally we have put the wrap panel it ItemPanelTemplate, but u have told to put the wrap panel inside the scrollviewer, so that I have put like that. I am not understand what you have came to tell.  Thanks for your reply